# Using paste0 function in R with httr

Tags: r, httr

I'm using `httr` inside of RStudio to query a website. I can successfully use the httr function like this:

```
test <- GET ("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=01:01&patdpb2=04:01&did=2&dondpb1=01:01&dondpb2=01:01")
```

I would like to have R query the website for each row in a tibble. I have written code that successfully constructs the correct html code using data from my tibble:

```
paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB11cd.donor))
```

I now want to use the output from the `paste0` function to query the website using `GET`.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to put the `paste0` function inside of the `GET` function. `GET` requires the html code to be inside quotes, like this: `GET ("https://example")`. However, when I try something like this: `GET ("(paste0("https://", mDPB11cd.recipient)")`, the quotes seem to mess everything up. How can I get the output of the `paste0` function to be inside quotes to work in the `GET` function?

Comment: The GET function does not require values to be inside quotes. It just needs a character value which is what paste0 will return. Don't use quotes. Just use `GET(paste0(...))`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(your_tibble))` in the question?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that httr is getting more than one url. This code: ```(BMT_cases_MM_matches 
   %>% slice(1:5)
   %>% mutate (url =  (GET (paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB11cd.donor)))))``` gives an error: "Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `url`. i `url = (...)`. x length(url) == 1 is not TRUE".

Comment: Am I using this incorrectly inside of ```mutate```? I'm trying to get the httr function to query the url for each row, and put that value in the new column.

Comment: Just to be clear, I verified that ```GET``` does not require values to be inside of  quotes. I'm still having the same problem, which means that quotes likely weren't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `paste0` or `paste`, using `sprintf` can ease to read.

```
url_format <- "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=%s&patdpb2=%s&did=2&dondpb1=%s&dondpb2=%s"

url <- sprintf(url_format,mDPB11cd.recipient,mDPB12cd.recipient,mDPB11cd.donor,mDPB11cd.donor)

test <- GET(url)
```

it works fine, but if you have to be stick to `paste0` let me know then I could think another way.

Comment: I see how that would work, but the ```sprintf``` function does the same thing as the ```paste0``` function. When I use this code: ```(BMT_cases_MM_matches 
   %>% slice(1:5)
   %>% mutate (url =  (paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB11cd.donor)))
   %>% GET (url)))``` I get an error: "Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE". It seems that the GET function is not taking the urls one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes. Just using `GET(paste0("https://", mDPB11cd.recipient)` will work fine. It returns a character vector which is what `GET` expects

Answer (score 0):

[From your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125151/using-paste0-function-in-r-with-httr/69126394#comment122174343_69125151), I think your issue is not `paste0` or `sprintf` but how you are applying the function `GET`.

`GET` will not work when you pass multiple url in it, use `map` to pass them one by one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(httr)

BMT_cases_MM_matches %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  mutate(url =  paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB11cd.donor), 
         data = map(url, GET))
```

Comment: You are correct. I used ```map``` and got it to query one by one. This is my code so far: ```DPB1_permisive <- BMT_cases_MM_matches 
   %>% slice(1:2)
   %>% mutate (url =  (paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB12cd.donor)))
   %>% mutate (result = map(url, GET))``` However, when I try to do the same with ```content``` to parse the result, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Adding the following line of code ```%>% map(result, content(as = "text"))``` gives the error "Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'result' not found," even though the previous line created "result" with a mutate function.

Comment: Trying instead to use the ```content``` function this way: ```%>% content(result, "text")``` gives the following error: "Error in content(., result, "text") : is.response(x) is not TRUE"

Comment: You should provide us with data to help you debug the issue correctly. Without data we are just guessing. Anyway, you may try `data = map(result, content, as = 'text'))`

Comment: I added data and some more explanation to a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69133093/using-httr-on-multiple-rows-of-a-data-frame