# Using httr on multiple rows of a data frame

Tags: r, purrr, httr

I am trying to use R to get a response from a URL. I can successfully write code to do so using `httr::GET` followed by `httr::content`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

test <- GET ("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=01:01&patdpb2=04:01&did=2&dondpb1=01:01&dondpb2=01:01") 
%>% content(as = "text")
```

I would like to do this for each row of a data frame. Data is similar to this:

```
test <- tribble(~case, ~mDPB11cd.recipient, ~mDPB12cd.recipient, ~mDPB11cd.donor, ~mDPB12cd.donor, 
101, "04:01", "01:01", "03:01", "04:01",
102, "04:01", "02:01", "04:01", "01:01",
103, "01:01", "104:01", "03:01", "05:01",)
```

I have written code to assemble the correct url for each row, and can get a response for each using `purrr::map`:

```
DPB1_permisive <- test 
%>% mutate (url =  (paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB12cd.donor))) 
%>% mutate (result = (map(url, GET)))
```

However, now I can't find any way to use `content` to parse the result that I got.

Appending

```
%>% content(result, as = "text")
```

to the code above gives an error of

> Error in content(., result, as = "text") : is.response(x) is not TRUE

It would seem that the result from the URL is not being written correctly in the data frame. The "result" column shows up as type "list," with each row having a value of "<S3: response>."

How can I get `content` to parse the responses?

Comment: This isn't about the question itself but assembling the URLs: I personally have had plenty of bugs trying to build URLs or other queries like this with `paste`, and would recommend using something from the `glue` package or `stringr::str_glue` instead. Much easier to manage which pieces need to go where

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I re-worked my code to use `str_glue` successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `map` to get data from `GET` request.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

test %>% 
  mutate(url = paste0("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/ipd/imgt/hla/dpb_v2.cgi?pid=1&patdpb1=", mDPB11cd.recipient, "&patdpb2=", mDPB12cd.recipient, "&did=2&dondpb1=", mDPB11cd.donor, "&dondpb2=", mDPB12cd.donor),
         result = map(url, GET), 
         data = map(result, content, as = "text"))

#   case mDPB11cd.recipie… mDPB12cd.recipie… mDPB11cd.donor mDPB12cd.donor url                      result data 
#  <dbl> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>          <chr>          <chr>                    <list> <lis>
#1   101 04:01             01:01             03:01          04:01          https://www.ebi.ac.uk/c… <resp… <chr…
#2   102 04:01             02:01             04:01          01:01          https://www.ebi.ac.uk/c… <resp… <chr…
#3   103 01:01             104:01            03:01          05:01          https://www.ebi.ac.uk/c… <resp… <chr…
```

Comment: That worked! I guess the solution is that I had to put the `GET` and `content` functions inside of the same `mutate` function. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Nick Brown they don't have to be inside the same `mutate` call, but they do need to be mapped in order to be vectorized

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was able to re-code it so that they were in separate `mutate` calls. I swear that's what I was attempting to do all night, but couldn't get it to work!